# Infinitely long canvas in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am creating a drawing app, with my canvas extending downwards from the screen and matching parent horizontally.

I would like the canvas to be as long as the user requires. So if they have a long drawing the can infinitely scroll down as they wish and continue drawing.  How can i achieve this?

thanks